# withLatestFrom() returns the whole state

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngxs

I have the following code:

```
@Select(CustomerState.customerProducts) customerProducts$: Observable<CustomerProduct[]>;

this.layouts$ = this.store.dispatch([
      new LoadCustomerProducts(),
    ]).pipe(
      withLatestFrom(this.customerProducts$),
      map(([customerProducts]) => {
        console.log('CP!!!', customerProducts);
        return this.loadLayouts(customerProducts);
      })
    );
```

The problem is that when i log the customerProducts I am expecting that it will only return array of customer product but instead it returns the whole state. Why is that so?

Thanks!

Comment: It can't know what portion of state you're going to change by `LoadCustomerProducts` action. Btw, `.dispatch` doesn't seem to return anything https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/8.0.1/modules/store/src/store.ts#L83-L86

Comment: @martin that's ngrx source I am using ngxs. BTW, there is already an answer. Thanks though!

Comment: Aaaaah, my bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`withLatestFrom` pushes the value from the provided `Observable` onto the array you're destructuring with `map`. If `store.dispatch` in ngxs returns the store `Observable`, you want:

```
this.layouts$ = this.store.dispatch([
      new LoadCustomerProducts(),
    ]).pipe(
      withLatestFrom(this.customerProducts$),
      map(([store, customerProducts]) => {
        console.log('CP!!!', customerProducts);
        return this.loadLayouts(customerProducts);
      })
    );
```

See: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/withLatestFrom

It's worth noting that `withLatestFrom` *will not* wait for `customerProducts$` to emit. Instead, when you subscribe to `layouts$`, you will immediately get the current state, but since `customerProducts$` has not yet emitted, `layout$` will not emit.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-efmtxp